# Keep training Keras model with loading and saving the weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Since I cannot install h5py due to package inconsistency I am wondering if it is possible to save and load the weights in Keras to keep training your model on a new data. I know I can do the following:

```
   old_weights = model.get_weights()
   del model
   new_model.set_weights(old_weights)
```

where model is the old model and new_model is the new one.Here is a complete example:

```
for i in training data:
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh', input_dim=Input))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=8, batch_size=16, shuffle=False, verbose=0)
    new_model = Sequential()
    new_model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh', input_dim=Input))
    new_model.add(Dense(1))
    new_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    old_weights = model.get_weights()
    del model
    new_model.set_weights(old_weights)
    model=new_model
```

I want after reading each training example (X and y are different at each iteration) save the weights and load it again and start from pre-trained model. I am not sure if my code does that since I am defining optimizer and model.compile again. Can anyone help me if the following code save the model and every iteration starts from pre-trained model.

Comment: I dont get your question! If you want to train a model couple of times inside a program, you can use fit multiple times, if you want to train a model and save weights to train it some other time, checkout save, load from keras, if your intending to save the model in each epoch, keras saving is all hdf5, you need to have tensorflow as backend to save weights as checkpoints.

Comment: I would like to train a model on one data set and save the weights then load the next data and use the pre-trained model to perform another training on the second data. (Don't want to start from scratch) Want to use the past weights and as the initializing for the next data set.

Comment: I want to train a model on the first data file then save the weights and perform another training with stored weight on the second dataset and so on

Comment: This code that you gave will not store any weights, and it equal to using fit many times, if you want to store (save in hard/ssd/...) The weights you need to have hdf5 or as i said another solution is if you have a tensorflow back end you can give callbacks to it, here is a reference: [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models)

Comment: @a-sam Thanks I will try your solution asap and let you know. what about successive calls to model.fir as it is proposed by jpandas?

Comment: @user59149 the proposed method by jpandas is completely correct, in case you don`t want to save any models on drive, as i said, the code you gave is exactly like calling fit multiple times in a loop

Comment: yes but is my code overrides the previous weights everytime I read new data ?

Comment: yes, that compile means that you initialize/override weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep recompiling the model. Instead just fit your model multiple times after loading your samples.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh', input_dim=Input))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# load the data into training_data 
for data in training_data:  
    model.fit(data[0], data[1], epochs=8, batch_size=16, shuffle=False, verbose=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this start from scratch every time I call the model.fit command? Does it remember the previous weights and biases? I want my model get a idea or be trained on all data and not reading 100 files and effectively every time overrides the previous weight vectors.

Comment: No, it will not start from scratch. Have a look at this https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4446.

Comment: Thanks I will test it quickly and let you know asap.